Почему nginx выдает 403, хотя у пользователя, под которым работает nginx, с правами доступа всё нормально
Я хочу сделать веб-доступ к моему HDD диску, который был примонтирован в директорию /home/hdd/storage, веб-досутп будет выдан к дочерней директории public. Вот права и владельцы этой директории и родительских:

/home:                    root:root 755
/home/hdd:                hdd:hdd   755
/home/hdd/storage:        hdd:hdd   755
/home/hdd/storage/public: hdd:hdd   775

Пользователь www-data, от имени которого работает nginx находится в группе hdd.
Вот моя конфигурация nginx для виртуального сервера:
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name xxx.net;

    error_page 404 /error/404;
    error_page 403 /error/403;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/xxx.net/certificate.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/xxx.net/private.key;

    allow all;
    root /home/www-data/xxx.net;

    location /hdd {
        alias /home/hdd/storage/public;
        autoindex on;
    }
}

В директорию /home/hdd/storage/public я для проверки закинул файл dlna.apk с правами 664 и с владельцем hdd:hdd:
merqury@merqury-server:~$ sudo -u www-data ls -l /home/hdd/storage/public/dlna.apk 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 hdd hdd 5153618 Aug 20 13:01 /home/hdd/storage/public/dlna.apk

При запросе на https://xxx.net/hdd я получаю содержимое директории в котором отображается dlna.apk, но при попытке его загрузить меня перенаправляет на страницу 403.

Другие решения пробовал, ничего не помогало: SELinux у меня нет, apparmor отключен, ACL у меня не установлен, вот глобальная конфигурация:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    gzip on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

В error.log нет логов связанных с 403

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.

@andreymal, Да он откусывает, но проблема в том что ссылки на веб-странице и редиректы не будут содержать префикса /router, например мой роутер при запросе на / редиректит на /cgi-bin/luci, а должен на /router/cgi-bin/luci, аналогично и ссылки на странице
